# Not everything is deleted when I uninstall

Tags: nsis

I've made a simple installer that installs test.txt, but there are several problems:

- The created folder+link in start menu isn't deleted
- The uninstaller + folder isn't deleted

Does anyone know why?

```
#defines
outFile "Installer.exe"
installDir $DESKTOP\test

section

    setOutPath $INSTDIR
    writeUninstaller $INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe
    createShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\TestApplication\Uninstaller.lnk" "$INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe"

    file test.txt

    messageBox MB_OK "Hello World!"


sectionEnd

section "Uninstall"
    delete $INSTDIR\uinstaller.exe
    delete "$SMPROGRAMS\TestApplication\Uninstaller.lnk"
    delete $INSTDIR\test.txt
sectionEnd
```

Comment: FWIW (I know you're not a native speaker), "ain't" is rarely appropriate in professional circles, and in English the word "I" is *always* capitalized.

Comment: I don't know about the rest, but you never delete the installation directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Shortcuts_removal_fails_on_Windows_Vista

and use `RmDir "$INSTDIR"` after the delete commands to delete the install folder

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers pointing out that you never call RmDir $INSTDIR, you've also mistyped the uninstaller executable name:

```
delete $INSTDIR\uinstaller.exe
```

You've missed the 'n'.